# SIGSEGV in 'free' function of libpthread, but backtrace does not list any of my files/funcs

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, opencl

I have an OpenCL program that uses only one device (GPU in this case) and I am using 3 pthreads to manage the program (plus the main thread).

Sometimes I get a SIGSEGV, but I have no clue why it happens.

Thread 13 "my_program" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

```
[Thread 0x7fffc5aef700 (LWP 20058) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc62f0700 (LWP 20057) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc6af1700 (LWP 20056) exited]

Thread 13 "my_program" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffa22ee700 (LWP 20181)]
─── Assembly ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
0x00007ffff6d7bfc2 free+-17256558 jne    0x7ffff6d7c070 <free+192>
0x00007ffff6d7bfc8 free+-17256552 test   %rdi,%rdi
0x00007ffff6d7bfcb free+-17256549 je     0x7ffff6d7c060 <free+176>
0x00007ffff6d7bfd1 free+-17256543 mov    -0x8(%rdi),%rax
0x00007ffff6d7bfd5 free+-17256539 lea    -0x10(%rdi),%rsi
0x00007ffff6d7bfd9 free+-17256535 test   $0x2,%al
0x00007ffff6d7bfdb free+-17256533 jne    0x7ffff6d7c018 <free+104>
─── Expressions ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─── History ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─── Memory ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─── Registers ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   rax 0x0000000000000000    rbx 0x0000000000000001    rcx 0x00007fffc6af19c0    rdx 0x00007fffc62f09c0
   rsi 0x0000000000000000    rdi 0x0005a9390005a938    rbp 0x0000000000622570    rsp 0x00007fffa22ede80
    r8 0x00007fff880008c0     r9 0x00000000ffffffff    r10 0x0000000000000000    r11 0x0000000000000206
   r12 0x00007fffc5aef700    r13 0x0000000000000000    r14 0x00007fffa22ee700    r15 0x0000000000000000
   rip 0x00007ffff6d7bfd1 eflags [ IF RF ]              cs 0x00000033             ss 0x0000002b
    ds 0x00000000             es 0x00000000             fs 0x00000000             gs 0x00000000
─── Source ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─── Stack ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[0] from 0x00007ffff6d7bfd1 in free+-17256543
(no arguments)
[1] from 0x00007ffff7dea5d6 in _dl_deallocate_tls+54
(no arguments)
[+]
─── Threads ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[20] id 20197 name my_program from 0x00007ffff79aacc6 in do_futex_wait.constprop
[19] id 20196 name my_program from 0x00007ffff79aacc6 in do_futex_wait.constprop
[18] id 20194 name my_program from 0x00007ffff79ab6db in __lll_lock_wait_private+12251451
[17] id 20188 name my_program from 0x00007ffff79ab6db in __lll_lock_wait_private+12251451
[16] id 20184 name my_program from 0x00007ffff79ab6db in __lll_lock_wait_private+12251451
[15] id 20183 name my_program from 0x00007ffff79ab6db in __lll_lock_wait_private+12251451
[14] id 20182 name my_program from 0x00007ffff79ab6db in __lll_lock_wait_private+12251451
[13] id 20181 name my_program from 0x00007ffff6d7bfd1 in free+-17256543
[12] id 20172 name my_program from 0x00007ffff6dd7177 in sched_yield+7
[11] id 20066 name si_shader_low:1 from 0x00007ffff79a838d in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2
[10] id 20065 name si_shader_low:0 from 0x00007ffff79a838d in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2
[9] id 20064 name si_shader:2 from 0x00007ffff79a838d in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2
[8] id 20063 name si_shader:1 from 0x00007ffff79a838d in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2
[7] id 20062 name si_shader:0 from 0x00007ffff79a838d in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2
[6] id 20061 name disk_cache:0 from 0x00007ffff79a838d in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2
[5] id 20059 name amdgpu_cs:0 from 0x00007ffff79a838d in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2
[1] id 19816 name my_program from 0x00007ffff6dd7177 in sched_yield+7
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
0x00007ffff6d7bfd1 in free () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
>>> bt
#0  0x00007ffff6d7bfd1 in free () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7dea5d6 in _dl_deallocate_tls () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#2  0x00007ffff79a1307 in __free_stacks () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff79a145a in __deallocate_stack () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff79a2354 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff6def47f in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

As you can see when I am doing `backtrace` I only get functions outside my program.

This is how I create and destroy one of these 3 pthreads.

```
int main(){
  //...
  pthread_t pthreadRead;
  pthread_attr_t attrRead;
  pthread_cond_init(&pcondRead, NULL);
  pthread_attr_init(&attrRead);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attrRead, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
  pthread_create(&pthreadRead, &attrRead, pthreadRead_func, NULL);

  //...
  // waits for completion (OpenCL)
  //...

  pthread_attr_destroy(&attrRead);
  //...
}
```

The main function of a thread:

```
void* pthreadRead_func(void* ptr) {

  bool cont = true;
  while (cont) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pmutexRead);
    while (!signaledRead) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&pcondRead, &pmutexRead);
    }

    // doing OpenCL calls and operations
    if (conditionMeet){
      cont = false;
    }

    signaledRead = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pmutexRead);
  }

  pthread_exit(0);
  return (void*)0;
}
```

How can I understand what is going on if I cannot track the error to my code?

```
#0  0x00007ffff6d7bfd1 in free () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7dea5d6 in _dl_deallocate_tls () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#2  0x00007ffff79a1307 in __free_stacks () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff79a145a in __deallocate_stack () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff79a2354 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff6def47f in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Are you using the `-g` during compilation? So you can get the debug symbols from your code. Ex.: `gcc -g source.c -pthread -o output` supposing you are compiling C source code.

Comment: Use std::thread, not pthreads.

Comment: Maybe try using only one thread, to see if resource sharing is at fault.

Comment: @manni66 is it C++?

Comment: @Ccampes Yes, compiled with -g. Tested in clang and in gcc. manni66 user: The design decision is to use pthreads. Are you saying that pthreads could have faults that are still, after dozens of years, not repaired? Ring user: With one thread OpenCL blocks my only thread and it has even more problems... I created these 3 threads solving previous concurrency issues by OpenCL.

Comment: @RingØ if it is not C++ it should not have a C++ tag.

Comment: Is it compiled with C++, but the code is completely C ported to be compiled by C++. So, I work with the lowest level of C++, that you almost cannot differenciate from C. This is important because my "knowledge" is C, and until I solve all the concurrency and OpenCL issues I don't want to use higher-level features. So, I tag C++ because it is a C++ program built with a c++ compiler.

Comment: That's the worst way you could do it.

Comment: That's the best way to do it if you care completely about performance... and still you want to start introducing C++ features.

Comment: @user3819881 if you think so, stay with C.

Comment: The error happens when it de-allocates thread local storage in [_dl_deallocate_tls](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/dl-tls.c;hb=a23aa5b7272ec4a04578d82399ec2bf536281119#l538). It is caused by the code you do not show here. Run your code under `valgrind`. And there is no good excuse for not using `std::thread` here and the C++ synchronization primitives. The only things that using `pthread` functions directly buy you here are bugs, performance is the same.

Comment: And that `pthread_exit` call is unnecessary because returning from the thread functions terminates the thread for you.

Comment: Did you notice that your application has 17 threads in fact?

Comment: But do you have any clue why it fails in this free/deallocate_tls? I ran the code under valgrind, and it is a mess.. up to 8000 errors, hard to analyze, all Possible Data race inside the OpenCL implementation libraries... not directly my code. 

The pthread_exit was just because I used valgrind and writting that call removed a couple of errors from valgrind. yes, 20 threads, but 16 are from OpenCL library (not my code). The other is the main thread + my 3 pthread.

Comment: Those who recommend me to jump to C++ completely to solve some of my problems. I tried just the simplest case (vecadd) and I run valgrind... have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519977/simple-hello-world-vecadd-opencl-program-in-c-valgrind-emits-up-to-10000-erro